# Drag and Drop between xtragrid and Scheduler

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, devexpress

someone can tell me how to drag and drop data between gridcontrol and schedulercontrol from devexpress? I want to drag the data from the grid and drop it on the scheduler. The devexpress example in the demo doesnt work for me. I just get a block-symbol.

regards

Comment: You've got a better chance of working out why that demo doesn't work for you than getting this code written for you from scratch. Cue the 'what have you tried so far' and 'post your code' comments....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it.

```
 private void grdGrid_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            posImGrid = null;

            GridHitInfo hitInfo = grvView.CalcHitInfo(new Point(e.X, e.Y));

            if (Control.ModifierKeys != Keys.None)
            {
                return;
            }

            if ((e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left) &&
                (hitInfo.InRow) &&
                (hitInfo.HitTest != GridHitTest.RowIndicator))
            {
                posImGrid = hitInfo;
            }
        }

        private void grdGrid_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if ((e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left) &&
                (posImGrid != null))
            {
                Size dragSize = SystemInformation.DragSize;
                Rectangle dragRect = new Rectangle(new Point(posImGrid.HitPoint.X - dragSize.Width / 2,
                                                             posImGrid.HitPoint.Y - dragSize.Height / 2), dragSize);

                if (!dragRect.Contains(new Point(e.X, e.Y)))
                {
                    grvView.GridControl.DoDragDrop(GetDragData(grvView), DragDropEffects.All);
                    posImGrid = null;
                }
            }
        }

        private SchedulerDragData GetDragData(GridView view)
    {
        Appointment termin = Storage.CreateAppointment(AppointmentType.Normal);
        clsMeineKlasse tempObjekt = (clsMeineKlasse)grvView.GetFocusedRow();
        termin.Description = tempObjekt.Beschreibung;
        termin.Subject = tempObjekt.Bezeichnung;
        termin.Duration = TimeSpan.FromHours(8);

        SchedulerDragData sdd = new SchedulerDragData(termin);

        return sdd;
    }
```